# How to combine a String of arrays to one string using loops?

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to combine all the Strings in an array to one String just by loops. How do I do it?

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String [] x = {"ab", "bc", "cd"};

        String z = concatination(x, 3);

        System.out.println(z);
    }

    public static String concatination(String [] array, int i ){

        for(int j = 0; j<array.length-1; j++){
            return (array[j]);
        }
        return " ";
    }
}
```

```
output: 
java unreachable statement

Expected output:
abbccd
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String [] x = {"ab", "bc", "cd"};

    String z = concatination(x);

    System.out.println(z);
}

public static String concatination(String[] array) {
    String concat = "";
    for(int j = 0; j<array.length; j++) {
        concat += array[j];
    }
    return concat;
}
```

OUTPUT:
`abbccd`

Comment: A good answer should explain the problem. What's obvious to you might not be so for others.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, ok thanks for the feedback. I'm still new here.

Comment: @Ridwan Thank you! How do you do the same with characters though?

Comment: @Priya, its going to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please try code below:-

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String [] x = {"ab", "bc", "cd"};
        
        String z = concatination(x, 3);

        //With loop
        System.out.println(z);
        //Without loop
        System.out.println(String.join("",x));
     }

    public static String concatination(String [] array, int i ){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int j = 0; j<array.length; j++){
            builder.append(array[j]);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: `String z = concatination(x, 3);` Why passing `3` as parameter when you are not going to use it.

Comment: No need to pass 3. Just copied given code :-)